# How to access label property of a selected option

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-formly

I know how to access the value of a selected option but what if I want to access the label that is displayed to the user. I want to be able to get both. I'm using formly form and this is how it looks like

```
vm.InwardLeaseFields = [
{
    className: 'row',
    fieldGroup: [
    {
        className: 'col-xs-3',
        key: 'supplier',
        type: 'select',
        templateOptions: {
            options: [],
            valueProp: 'supplierCode',
            labelProp: 'supplierName',
            required: false,
            onChange: function() {
                console.log('vm.InwardLeaseModel.supplier.supplierName');
                console.log(vm.InwardLeaseFields.supplier.supplierName);
            }
        }
    }
}];
```

The vm.InwardLeaseFields.supplier only returns the value.

Comment: Downvoting and not suggesting anything isn't going to help to be honest...

Comment: What do you need the label for?

Comment: @Protozoid I have to pass both label and value to a web service as separate properties.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out a workaround myself.

```
onChange: function(val, key) {
    vm.InwardLeaseModel.supplier = vm.getSupplierName(val, key);
}
```

and the function

```
vm.getSupplierName = function(value, key) {
    var selectedSupplierCode = value;

    if(!selectedSupplierCode) {
        return '';
    } else {
        for(var i = 0; i < key.templateOptions.options.length; i++) {
            if(key.templateOptions.options[i].supplierCode == selectedSupplierCode) {
                return key.templateOptions.options[i].supplierName;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
};
```